# Iterating over multiple arrays in JSON object in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I've been trying to return the first object of the first array in my JSON object, but I'm having some trouble.

I want to return the name of the first "vitamins", which is "Vitamin B2", in an  tag.

Here is my JSON object

```
{
  "nutrients": {
    "vitamins": [{
      "name": "Vitamin B2",
      "current": "1.7"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vitamin B6",
        "current": "10.9"
    }],
      "minerals": [{
        "name": "Zinc",
        "current": "1.7"
    }]
  }
}
```

And here is my code trying to map over it

```
import nutrients from '../../vitamins.json';

renderData() {
  return Object.keys(nutrients).map((nutrient, index) => {
    console.log('it works', nutrient[0].name, index);
    return (
      <option value="" key={index}>{nutrient[0].name}</option>
    )
  }
)}
```

Comment: "nutrients['vitamins'][0].name"  this is enough

Comment: There are no arrays in [JSON Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: You need to parse that JSON into a real JS object before doing any manipulation on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a ={
  "nutrients": {
    "vitamins": [{
      "name": "Vitamin B2",
      "current": "1.7"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vitamin B6",
        "current": "10.9"
    }],
      "minerals": [{
        "name": "Zinc",
        "current": "1.7"
    }]
  }
}

console.log(a.nutrients['vitamins'][0].name)
```

Comment: Great, this works. Thanks. Now what if I want to return all of the names? If I do console.log(micros.nutrients['vitamins'].name), I get "undefined".

Comment: a.nutrients['vitamins'].forEach(item =>{
  console.log(item.name)
});

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the entire object to be in state.data

```
`render(){
 const {vitamins}=this.state.data.nutrients;
 vitamins.map((item,index)=>{
     if(index === 0)
     {    return (<div>item.name</div>)
     }`
  })
 }`
```

the output will print Vitamin-B2

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped.

Comment: The reason why you wrapped {vitamins} in a curly brace in const {vitamins} is because it's the name of an object, so it has to be wrapped in {}?

Comment: @bigjohnjr it is an ES6 shorthand.

Comment: `const {vitamins} =this.state.data.nutrients` when expanded becomes `this.state.data.nutrients.vitamins`. It's the same thing but it helps in code clarity and ease of understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could use logic something like below:

```js
let nutrientObj = {
  "nutrients": {
    "vitamins": [{
      "name": "Vitamin B2",
      "current": "1.7"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vitamin B6",
        "current": "10.9"
    }],
      "minerals": [{
        "name": "Zinc",
        "current": "1.7"
    }]
  }
}

let nutrients = nutrientObj.nutrients;
let firstElement = nutrients[Object.keys(nutrients)[0]];

console.log(firstElement && firstElement.length ? firstElement[0].name : "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use destructuring in ES6, use this as reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring

```
import nutrients from '../../vitamins.json'
renderData() {
  const { nutrients: { vitamins: [{ name: vitaminName }] }  } = nutrients; //it destructures the given object, it will directly fetch the vitamin B2.
  console.log("Vitamin Name is = "+vitaminName)
  <option value="">{vitaminName}</option>
}
```